# Convergence of random variables implying almost sure convergence (where is the flaw?)

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

This would probably look like a dumb question (akin to prove $2=1$ type). But I'd still like to know where the flaw lies.
The question is regarding convergence in probability and almost sure convergence. 
We know the following:
Suppose events $A_n \to A$, then $P(A_n) \to P(A)$ i.e $\lim P(A_n) =  P(\lim A_n) = P(A)$.

Can't the same principle be used to conclude equivalence of both type of convergence?

$P(\lim X_n = X) = \lim P(X_n = X)$, implying equivalence?
Thanks!

Best,

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Thanks for the edits!... sorry for being (extremely) sloppy at first!

Answer (score 0):

If you write the parentheses in your second line instead of being sloppy, you see what happens:

In your first example, you use that if $A_n \to A$, then $P(A_n) \to P(A)$. If you want to use that for $\{X_n = X\}$ as you do, you must have $\{X_n = X\} \to \{X=X\} = \Omega$ or something like that. See also that in your first example, the right hand side $P(A)$ doesn't contain a limit, but the one in the second does. Please be more exact.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the first example...its corrected now...thanks for the answer!